# Combining OpenCV 2.1 with OpenCV 2.3.2 to keep speed on CPU and leverage GPU execution

Tags: performance, opencv, gpu

I have noticed that moving to OpenCV 2.3.1 has had an execution time penalty. The C based code in 2.1 runs much faster than the 2.3.1 equivalent. I need a way to combine both sets of code into the same exe. I have tried using different libs and trying to wrap the issues but the linker sees the common symbols and shows the error. Has anyone tried to do this or should I just accept 2.3.1 and get my algorithms into the GPU and run them there for performance.

Comment: What platform are we talking about?

Comment: If you think 2.3 is slower than 2.1, i think it would be better have some timing calculations and discuss it with opencv developers at `www.code.opencv.org`.

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that there is a significant slowdown from 2.1 -> 2.3.1, generally each release has improved on speed.

Are you sure you are using 2.3.1 correctly? Do you have it built with TBB (somewhere between 2.0 and 2.3 they switched to TBB over OMP for multithreading).  Are you linking to a debug build?

There is a set of performance measurement tests in the distribution you can use to check what (if any) functions are slowing you down.